# Какую роль играют float и double в скобках?

Tags: float, double

Это программа для вычисления машинного эпсиона, какую роль играют *float* и *double* в скобках и почему без них решение выводиться не то, что находится в библиотеке *float.h*

```
    #include<float.h>
    #include<stdio.h>

    float eps = 1.0;
    while ((float)(1 + eps/2.0) != 1.0){ 
        eps /= 2.0;
    }

    printf("%e\n", eps);
    printf("%e\n", FLT_EPSILON);

    double epsi = 1.0;
    while ((double)((1 + epsi/2.0) != 1.0)){
        epsi /= 2.0;
    }

    printf("%e\n", epsi);
    printf("%e\n", DBL_EPSILON);
```

Comment: Это явное приведение (иными словами преобразование) типа выражения. (Еще его обычно называют cast). По умолчанию тип выражения `(1 + eps/2.0)` будет double (поскльку константа 2.0 имеет тип double. Все выражение `(float)(1 + eps/2.0)` будет иметь тип float. В данном контексте это абсолютно бессмысленно, поскольку для сравнения с 1.0 (default double) выражение `(float)(1 + eps/2.0)` будет тут же опять преобразовано в тип double. / Мне крайне интересно, откуда вы берете такие примеры?

Comment: @avp, при преобразовании `double` -> `float` -> `double` происходит округление. Без него оба кода вернули бы ульп для double. В данном случае это очень осмысленно.

Answer (score 0):

Ключевое слово `float` и `double` используется для объявления переменных с плавающей точкой одинарной и двойной точности соответственно. В данной программе они используются для приведения результата выражения к типу переменной с плавающей точкой.

В условии цикла `while` используется сравнение двух чисел, одно из которых получено путем деления `eps` на 2 и прибавлением единицы, а второе - просто единица. Сравнение проводится с помощью оператора `!=`. Если сравнение истинно, то цикл продолжается, в противном случае - прерывается.

Сравнение на равенство двух переменных типа float или double может быть неточным из-за ограниченной точности хранения чисел с плавающей точкой в компьютере. Используя `(float)` и `(double)` перед выражением в скобках, мы приводим результат к типу переменной с плавающей точкой соответствующей точности.

Если убрать скобки с выражения, то произойдет следующее: сначала выполнится деление переменной `eps` на 2.0, затем результат будет прибавлен к единице. Затем это выражение сравнится с единицей, используя оператор `!=`. В результате получится сравнение чисел разных типов (типа `float` и `int`), что может привести к некорректному результату.

Чтобы получить точный результат, программа использует константы `FLT_EPSILON` и `DBL_EPSILON`, которые определяют машинный эпсилон для типов `float` и `double` соответственно. Сравнивая результаты, полученные в цикле с этими константами, мы можем определить, какой результат является более точным.